# Regex C doesn't work as expected with wild card * and caret

Tags: c, regex

I have written regex code using regex library in C. But I am facing few problems with wild card * and Caret.

Following is my regex code:

```
status = regcomp (&r, tmp, REG_EXTENDED);
if(!status) {
    if(regexec(&r, string_to_compare, 0, NULL, 0) == 0) {
        /* Do something */
    }
}
```

where tmp is a string pattern and string_to_compare is just a string which has to be matched with regex r.

Case 1: * not working as expected.

a. With pattern "n1*"

Following strings are passed in string_to_compare:

```
to-dallas
newyork-to-dallas1
n1
```

regexec returns 0 for all above strings, while it is expected to return 0 for string n1.

Working case:

With pattern "newyork-to-dallas*"

with same strings passed as above,

regexec returns 0 only for "newyork-to-dallas1".

Case 2: Caret not working as expected.

With pattern "^to-da*" and same strings as above, regexec doesnt return 0 for all the strings.

Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `*` isn't usually a wild card in regular expressions.

Comment: `*` usually means match the previous expression `0` or more times in regex. No experience with C, so maybe someone could verify that this is the behaviour.

Comment: `*` is a quantifier meaning the preceding character can occur 0 or more times. You probably want `^to-da.*` which should match anything after `to-da`. The `.` is any single character so you're saying 0 or more any characters. Currently you are saying any string that starts with `to-d`, `to-daa`, or `to-daaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`, etc

Comment: @chris85 Thank you so much for the explanation. Case 1 is working with the new pattern "n1.*". 

But regexec with pattern "^to-da.*" still does not seem to return 0 for string "to-dallas". By this I mean, ^ does not seem to work. Am I missing something here as well?

Comment: I'm not sure how C handles the carat. The carat means the start of the string so perhaps there is whitespace or something else preceding the `to-dallas`?

Comment: @chris85 I verified that there's no whitespace preceding `to-dallas`. Does it have anything to do with regex flags passed to `regcomp`?

Comment: Is it a multi-lined string, or just `to-dallas`?

Comment: It is just `to-dallas`.

Comment: Okay, than outside my area, might be something specific to C.

Comment: This, from [a random web page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html): ".. otherwise, it shall return non-zero indicating either no match or an error. [..] The following constants are defined as error return values: ..." may be handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, `*` is a quantifier in a regular expression that means *0 or more occurrences*. Replacing it with `.*` should yield expected results.

Note that `n1*` also matches any `n` inside an input string, as it means `n` and an optional `1` (0 or more occurrences). `n1.*` already needs `n1` to be present in a string in order to return a match.

```
run("n1.*", "to-dallas");          // => No match
run("n1.*", "newyork-to-dallas1"); // => No match
run("n1.*", "n1");                 // => Match "n1"
```

As for `newyork-to-dallas*` (and `newyork-to-dallas.*`), it will match `newyork-to-dallas1`:

```
run("newyork-to-dallas*","newyork-to-dallas1"); // => Matches "newyork-to-dallas"
run("newyork-to-dallas.*","newyork-to-dallas1"); // => Matches "newyork-to-dallas1" as .* matches "1"
```

As for caret, it matches at the beginning of the string.

```
// Caret
run("^to-da.*", "to-dallas");          => Matches "to-dallas"
run("^to-da.*", "newyork-to-dallas1"); => No match (not at the beginning)
run("^to-da.*", "n1");                 => No match
```

See the full [demo program on CodingGround](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVGZ0YUpYSzV5VFk)